# Ionic getting fingerprint of the user using an external biometric scanner and store the result in my application

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-fingerprint-api

I am looking for a solution similar to Aadhar card or Jio sim where I will have a external biometric scanner connected to the phone through USB and when the device captures the fingerprint I need to store/compare the fingerprints in my application . The mobile devices which I am going to use for this application  already has an inbuild fingerprint scanner and if I am able to use that instead of an external scanner then it is well and good.I am looking for a cordova plugins which can help me to accomplish this . 
Thanks

Comment: any updates regarding this? Did you find any solution?